# How to hydrate Vue.js with server-side-rendered content from CMS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

Let's say, this is the situation:

- content is managed through a "classic" CMS like WordPress or TYPO3
- content is delivered by the CMS as fully rendered HTML and CSS

In the Frontend **Vue.js** should be used for all interactions with the UI.

---

Even though I read most of vue's documentantion and also the page [Vue.js Server-Side Rendering Guide](https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/) as well as [Usage in non-Node.js Environments](https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/non-node.html), I'm still not sure how to make this work.

---

#### An example<sup>*</sup>

The page has a *component* which is basically a list of products. For eveybody with JavaScript this list gets a filter on top.

Now, from the CMS I get the full rendered list, like:

```
<div class="product-component">
    <ul class="products">
        <li data-id="1">Product 1</li>
        <li data-id="2">Product 2</li>
        <li data-id="3">Product 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

After the JavaScript ran, it should look like this:

```
<div id="product-component">
    <form>
        <select>
            <option value="1">Show Product 1 only</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    
    <ul class="products"></ul>
</div>
```

---

The component in Vue.js could be something like this:

```
<div id="product-component">
    <form>
        <!-- Vue.js logic for the filter -->
    </form>

    <ul class="products">
        <li v-for="product in products">
            {{ product.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#product-component',
  data: {
    products: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Product 1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Product 2'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Product 3'},
    ],
    filterCurrent: null,
  }
});
```

---

Now my questions are:

- How to hook Vue.js into a prerendered Template?
- How to update/inject Vue.js variables (especially `data`) on runtime?

  - Which means: How can I get the list of products from the CMS into the component?
- As the list and by that parts of the template are rendered already, must Vue.js re-render it, after its initialisation?
- How is this represented in [Vue.js' Lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)?

Last but not least: *Is setup this even possible?*

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> The code is just pseudocode to illustrate the problem.</sub>

Comment: I don't see why you would hook into pre-rendered code. It is not really the concept of Vue. The majority of large scale frameworks like Wordpress have API's to gather data for you. This way you can simply cast this data to JSON and feed it to your components. Even if you could hook into pre-rendered code, you are doing twice the amount of work.

Comment: @Stephan-v Hm, I don't think that e.g. TYPO3 has an API for such a use-case. Also progressive enhancement wouldn't be possible, right? Is there another method, where I can hook the server side rendering of Vue inbetween on the server? Or am I stuck with jQuery as the only framework I could use?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a good solution for your question?

Comment: Please also see here for a similar (yet not identical) use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61043632/how-can-values-be-passed-to-vue-js-from-within-a-server-rendered-template-i-e

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are in your own extension, it is no problem to render the data via JSON. Vue.js can fetch them and take over the frontend rendering.

Comment: This is an old thread but as a Vue noob I still don't see the answer. Let's say your backend is PHP and it is generating this JSON. So -- use PHP to print the Vue components? Or are we saying, load the page and then use xhr to hydrate the Vue components? That would be two http requests instead of one, wouldn't it.

Comment: OK here's a comment on my own comment above: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html